# Why countLines and/or read.delim works in some files but not in others that were generated in the same way?

Tags: r

I have several files that are generated by Perl and C scripts. They are basically a large tsv file with a header, with the particular characteristic of having a list with sample names at the end of the file.

If I attempt to read this file with `read.delim()`I get the error:

"Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

This is caused by the list of samples at the end of the file. Originally I was making a copy of the file and deleting the list from shell, but then I decided to just tell R how to read the file, so I wrote a small function that uses `countLines{R.utils}` and the number of samples (which I know for each file) to tell `read.delim()` to ignore the nasty list. I looks something like this:

```
readmyfile<- function (tsv, nsamps) {
  tsv= tsv #the path to the tsv file
  nsamps= nsamps #the number of samples as listed at the end of the file

  # Count lines and rest the number of samples
  maxl<-countLines(tsv) - nsamps

  # Read the file ignoring the lines of the list of samples
  data.cov = read.delim(tsv, header = T, row.names = 1, nrows=maxl)
}
```

It worked very well and I used it with several files. Then, some weeks later, I generated other files and tried the function again. But this time I'm getting the error:

"Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

[Here you can download an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzS2pnCslHlXQndBTnE2WWVLSjg/edit?usp=sharing) of a "good" and "bad" file. If you download them and try:

```
readmyfile("goodfile.COV", 92)
```

You will see that it is working, but that:

```
> readmyfile("badfile.COV", 38)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

I have no idea what is going on. As far as I can tell the files are generated in the same way, and I work in the same computer (MacBook Pro) . I can't remember if I did something in particular to the files that work properly, the only thing I would think of was to make sure the line endings were LF. But this is not solving the issue.

Any clues? Oh please.

Comment: I was able to read both files with no default options set in `read.delim()`. Maybe sampling/subsetting after importing would work better?

Comment: Your column names could be running a muck too. It could be reading `# Catalog ID` as three separate columns.

Comment: Urm. You are right. read.delim() works fine (I could swear it didn't when I first wrote the function). Any advice on how to delete the list at the end after importing?

Comment: The weird thing is that it works with one file and not the other, and as far as I see the columns look the same

Comment: Try removing `row.names=1` from your `read.delim` in the `readmyfile` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `row.names=1` from your `read.delim` code allowed the function to work as expected:

```
readmyfile<- function (tsv, nsamps) {
  tsv= tsv #the path to the tsv file
  nsamps= nsamps #the number of samples as listed at the end of the file

  # Count lines and rest the number of samples
  maxl<-countLines(tsv) - nsamps

  # Read the file ignoring the lines of the list of samples
  data.cov = read.delim(tsv, header = T, nrows=maxl)
}
```

Comment: You are right, that was the issue. Just had to change the rownames later on. Thanks.